# Null coalescing on a dict entry in python

Tags: python, dictionary, null-coalescing

So, I'm aware that, in Python I can do this:

```
variable_name = other_variable or 'something else'
```

...and that that will assign `'something else'` to `variable_name` if `other_variable` is falsy, and otherwise assign `other_variable` value to `variable`.

Can I do a nice succinct similar thing with a dict:

```
variable_name = my_dict['keyname'] or 'something else'
```

...or will a non-existent keyname always raise an error, cause it to fail?

Comment: use the `get` method `my_dict.get('keyname',  'something else')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will see `KeyError` if `'keyname'` does not exist in your dictionary. Instead, you can use:

```
variable_name = my_dict.get('keyname', False) or 'something else'
```

With this logic, `'something else'` is assigned when either `'keyname'` does not exist or `my_dict['keyname']` is Falsy.

Comment: You answer is correct, but I'd like to point out that what we usually need in this scenario is `my_dict.get('keyname', 'something else')`.

Comment: @Gabriel, No, `my_dict.get('keyname', 'something else')` will be incorrect for `my_dict = {'key_name':0}`. In this scenario, OP will want `'something else'`.

Comment: I know and that's why I said your answer is correct. I just noted that when dealing with dicts we USUALLY (not always) want a default for missing keys, not falsey values.

Comment: @Gabriel, OK, I thought OP was very clear in his/her explanation. We'll wait to see if there's more clarification.

Comment: OP was 100% clear and that's why I can say you're correct (otherwise I couldn't say that for sure). My previous advise is for anyone who can read your answer, not only OP. For example, if someone had optional arguments in a function (as in `f(a=None)`) and converted to kwargs, one would want to test for missing keys, not falsey values. It may not be obvious by reading your answer, so I left an advice. I wasn't implying your answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks!  To be honest, I didn't _think_ I meant this, but it's made me realise that this scenario is exactly what I need. :)